# Eigenvectors of a matrix with entries involving combinatorics

Tags: co.combinatorics, matrices, special-functions, eigenvector

In the question [Eigenvalues of a matrix with entries involving combinatorics](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/255141/eigenvalues-of-a-matrix-with-entries-involving-combinatorics) No_way asked about eigenvectors of $n\times n$ matrix $M$ with entries \begin{eqnarray*}
M_{ij}=(-1)^{i+j}F(n, l, i, j), 
\end{eqnarray*}
where $F(n,l,i,j)$ is the cardinality of the set
\begin{eqnarray*}
\{(k_1, \cdots, k_n)\in\mathbb{Z}^{n}|0\leq k_r\leq l-1\text{ for }1\leq r\leq n\text{, }k_1+\cdots+k_n=lj-i\}.
\end{eqnarray*}
These eigenvalues are known to be $1, l, l^2, \cdots, l^{n-1}$.

Let's remove signs and consider the matrix $M$ with $M_{ij}=F(n, l, i, j)$. According to my numerical experiments eigenvectors do not depend on $l$ for $l\ge 2$ and they are polynomials.

> **Q1:** Why do eigenvectors not depend on $l$?

For $l=2$ we have $M_{ij}=\binom n{2j-i},$ and first examples are (eigenvectors of $M$ are rows of $V$)
$$n=2,\qquad M=\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 2 & 0 \\
 1 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right),\qquad V=\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 1 & 1 \\
 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right);$$
$$n=3,\qquad M=\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 3 & 1 & 0 \\
 1 & 3 & 0 \\
 0 & 3 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right),\qquad V=\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 1 & 1 & 1 \\
 -1 & 1 & 3 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right);$$

$$n=4,\qquad M=\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 4 & 4 & 0 & 0 \\
 1 & 6 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 4 & 4 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 6 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right),\qquad V=\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
 -1 & 0 & 1 & 2 \\
 2 & -1 & 2 & 11 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right);$$

$$n=5,\qquad M=\left(
\begin{array}{ccccc}
 5 & 10 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 1 & 10 & 5 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 5 & 10 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 10 & 5 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 5 & 10 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right),\qquad V=\left(
\begin{array}{ccccc}
 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
 -3 & -1 & 1 & 3 & 5 \\
 11 & -1 & -1 & 11 & 35 \\
 -3 & 1 & -1 & 3 & 25 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right).$$

Denote by $v_m=(v_m(1),\ldots,v_m(n))$ rows of $V$ ($0\le m\le n-1$). They defined up to multiplicative constant and $v_m(k)=\mu_m P_m(k)$ where $P_m(x)$ are some special polynomials of degree $m$. In particular for $m=0,1,2,3,4$ we have $$P_0(x)=1,\quad P_1(x)=2x-n,\quad P_2(x)=3x^2-3nx+\frac{n(3n-1)}{4},$$
$$P_3(x)=4x^3-6nx^2+n(3n-1)x-\frac{n^2(n-1)}{2},$$
$$P_4(x)=5x^4-10nx^3+\frac{5n(3n-1)}{2}x^2-\frac{5n^2(n-1)}{2}x+\frac{n(15n^3-30n^2+5n+2)}{48}.$$

> **Q2:** What is the generating function for these polynomials?

Comment: Have you noticed that the coefficient of $x^k$ in $P_m(x)$ seems to be essentially the same for constant $m-k$? More precisely, 
$[x^m]P_m=m+1, [x^{m-1}]P_m=- {{m+1}\choose{2}}n,  [x^{m-2}]P_m=+  {{m+1}\choose3}\dfrac {n(3n-1)}4, $ $[x^{m-3}]P_m=-{{m+1}\choose4}\dfrac{n^2(n-1)}{2}, [x^{m-4}]P_m={{m+1}\choose5}\dfrac{n(15n^3-30n^2+5n+2)}{48}...$ So we would only need to know $P_m(0)$, i.e. the polynominals in $n$ which are the constant terms of $P_m(x)$.

Comment: @Wolfgang Nice argument. It means that $P_m(x)$ is something like binomial convolution of $P_m=P_m(0)$ with falling factorials. It correspond to the product of two exponential generating functions and we only need to know exponential generating function for $P_m$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In fact for a fixed $n$, the matrices $M(l, n)$ for $l>0$ commute with each other and thus are simultaneously diagonalisable. For your second question, if $\{p_j(y)\}$ is a sequence of polynomials satisfying 
\begin{eqnarray}
\left(\frac{t}{\sinh t}\right)^y=\sum_{j=0}^\infty p_j(y)t^{2j}.
\end{eqnarray}
then the $i$-th entry of an eigenvector corresponding to the eigenvalue $l^{n-k-1}$ is 
\begin{eqnarray}
(-1)^{i-1}\sum_{j=0}^{\lfloor\frac{k}{2}\rfloor}\frac{p_j(n)}{(k-2j)!}(n-2i)^{k-2j}.
\end{eqnarray}
I believe from here we can work out what the generating function of your $P_m(x)$ is.