# Is the matrix $\left({2m\choose 2j-i}\right)_{i,j=1}^{2m-1}$ nonsingular?

Tags: co.combinatorics, linear-algebra, linear-programming, nonlinear-optimization

Suppose we have a $(2m-1) \times (2m-1)$ matrix defined as follows:
$$\left({2m\choose 2j-i}\right)_{i,j=1}^{2m-1}.$$

For example, if $m=3$, the matrix is

$$\begin{pmatrix}6 & 20 & 6& 0 & 0\newline 1 & 15 & 15 & 1 & 0 \newline 0 & 6 & 20 & 6 & 0 \newline 0 & 1 & 15 & 15 & 1 \newline 0 & 0 & 6 & 20 & 6 \end{pmatrix}$$

Can anyone tell me how to prove it is nonsingular?

Comment: Do $i, j$ start with $1$?

Comment: @T.Amdeberhan yes

Comment: Then, the determinant equals $2^{\binom{2m}2}\neq0$ and hence the matrix is regular/invertible.

Comment: If $i$ and $j$ start with $0$, numerically the determinant seems to be $2^{A024920} * A063079$ although there are a lot of related sequences, and there might be some pretty simple way to put it. http://oeis.org/A024920 http://oeis.org/A063079

Comment: Are you defining $\binom ab$ to be 0 if $b<0$ or $b>a$?

Comment: @AnthonyQuas yes

Comment: There should be a proof using Lindström-Gessel-Viennot.

Comment: (1) This reminds me of a problem I can't quite remember where some sort of Mobius inversion came in handy.  (2) I really want to somehow factor the thing.

Comment: Well, it's pretty exciting that this matrix seems to count domino tilings of an Aztec diamond.

Comment: Just like the matrix of entries $\binom{2i}j$ for $0\leq i, j\leq 2m-1$.

Comment: It seems that the eigenvalues of $\left({n+1\choose 2j-i}\right)_{i,j=1}^{n}$ are ${2,2^2,\dots\,2^n}.$

Comment: See also http://mathoverflow.net/questions/255869/eigenvectors-of-a-matrix-with-entries-involving-combinatorics and http://mathoverflow.net/questions/255141/eigenvalues-of-a-matrix-with-entries-involving-combinatorics

Answer (score 31):

This is an instance of Holte's [Amazing matrix](https://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/2974981.pdf). Consider addition of binary digits. Start with a *carry* of $c \in \{0,1,\ldots,2(m-1)\}$. Choose $2m-1$ bits uniformly at random, and add their sum to $c$. If the total is in $2c' + \{0,1\}$ then the new carry is $c' \in \{0,1,\ldots,2(m-1)\}$. Amazingly enough the matrix in the question is the transition matrix for this Markov process, scaled by $2^{2m-1}$.

Holte proves that the eigenvalues of the transition matrix are $1$, $1/2$, $1/4$, $\ldots$, $1/2^{2(m-1)}$. (This agrees with Johann Cigler's comment above.) The eigenvectors can be expressed using Eulerian numbers: see Theorem 3 in Holte. 
Anyway, this shows the matrix is non-singular.

Answer (score 26):

The [Lindstrom-Gessel-Viennot lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lindstr%C3%B6m%E2%80%93Gessel%E2%80%93Viennot_lemma) says that the number of families of nonintersecting lattice paths can be counted by a determinant. Let $a_i = (2m-i,i)$. Let $b_j = (2m-2j,-2m+2j)$. Then the number of $(1,0)-(0,1)$ lattice paths from $b_j$ to $a_i$ is $2m \choose 2j-i$. By the Lindstrom-Gessel-Viennot lemma, the number of nonintersecting families of lattice paths from $\{b_j\}$ to $\{ a_i\}$ is $Det\left( {2m \choose 2j-i} \right)$. So, if we find a single nonintersecting family then the matrix is nonsingular. One such family is to connect the points in reverse order, connecting $(-2m+2k,2m-2k)$ to $(k,2m-k)$, and on each path, taking all $k$ vertical steps before all $2m-k$ horizontal steps. So, the determinant is positive.

Of course, it would be nice to evaluate this determinant which seemsto be $2^{2m \choose 2}$. I suspect that there is a correspondence with domino tilings of an Aztec diamond, but I don't see it yet.

Answer (score 21):

Here is a very low-brow answer to the original question.

Consider the lower-triangular matrix
\begin{equation*}
V = [V_{ij}] = \left[\binom{i-1}{j-1}\right]\quad \text{for}\quad i \ge j.
\end{equation*}

Let $A$ be the matrix in the OP. Then, a quick induction shows that $V^{-1}AV$ is upper triangular (use that $V^{-1}$ has entries $(-1)^{i-j}V_{ij}$), with the diagonal: $[2^n,2^{n-1},\ldots,2]$, which not only establishes invertibility of $A$, but also yields its eigenvalues.

Comment: Neat. You might also like this problem http://mathoverflow.net/questions/258448/in-search-of-a-transformation-between-determinants

Comment: @T.Amdeberhan I actually saw that cool question of yours, and while thinking about it, realized that $V$ triangularizes your matrix :-) For that problem of yours, I found some transformations, but not yet a full answer!

Comment: Looking forward.

Comment: Given the abundance of factors  of $2$ in the eigenvalues I wonder if there is a further decomposition of this  matrix (and the one in the other question).

Comment: @PietroMajer The matrix $V$ above is the famous Pascal matrix, and there are several papers exploring more refined decompositions involving Pascal matrices, so I wouldn't be surprised if there were more refined decompositions available.

Answer (score 15):

Let $A_n(x,\lambda)$ be the $n\times n$ matrix
$$\left[\binom{x}{2j-i+\lambda}\right]_{i,j=1}^n.$$
Let's "generalize to trivialize". Sometimes, generalizations offer more elbow room to maneuver, such as in the present problem.

**Lemma.** We have the determinantal formula
$$\det A_n(x,\lambda)=2^{\binom{n}2}\prod_{i=1}^n\binom{n+x-1}{\lambda+2i-1}\binom{n+x-1}{n-i}^{-1}.$$
**Proof.** We employ the [Method of Condensation](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1010.3881.pdf). Denote $k\times k$ sub-matrices with left-corner at $(a,b)$:
$$Z_k^{a,b}(x,\lambda)=\left[\binom{x}{2(j+b)-(i+a)+\lambda}\right]_{i,j=1}^k.$$
Notice that $Z_n^{0,0}(x,\lambda)=A_n(x,\lambda)$. In general $Z_k^{a,b}(x,\lambda)=A_k(x,\lambda+2b-a)$, therefore the inductive proofs neatly work with this Dodgson's recursive relation
$$\det Z_n^{a,b}=\frac{\det Z_{n-1}^{a,b}\cdot\det Z_{n-1}^{a+1,b+1}-\det Z_{n-1}^{a,b+1}\cdot\det Z_{n-1}^{a+1,b}}{\det Z_{n-2}^{a+1,b+1}}.$$
So, it remains to prove that the (explicit) formula on the RHS of the lemma *does* satisfy the same equation. However, this is quite a routine simplification (preferably with symbolic sofwares). The proof is complete. $\square$

**Corollary 1.** Your determinant evaluates as $2^{\binom{2m}2}$.

**Proof.** Take $n=2m-1, x=2m, \lambda=0$ in $A_n(x,\lambda)$ and simplify the RHS of the lemma. $\square$

Given a function $F(y_1,\cdots,y_{2m-1})$, denote the *constant term* of $F$ w.r.t. $y_i$ by $CT_i(F)$ and let $CT=\prod_{i=1}^{2m-1}CT_i$. We now register a nice consequence. A bonus, say to say.

**Corollary 2.** If $V(z_1,\dots,z_{2m-1})$ denotes the determinant of the [Vandermonde matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix) then
$$CT\left(\prod_{i=1}^{2m-1}y_i^{i-2}(1+y_i)^{2m}V(y_1^{-2},\dots,y_{2m-1}^{-2})\right)=2^{\binom{2m}2}.$$
**Proof.** Since $\binom{2m}{2j-i}=CT_i(y_i^{i-2j}(1+y_i)^{2m})$,
\begin{align} \det\left[\binom{2m}{2j-i}\right]
&=\det\left[CT_i(y_i^{i-2j}(1+y_i)^{2m})\right]
=CT\prod_{i=1}^{2m-1}y_i^i(1+y_i)^{2m}\det\left[y_i^{-2j}\right] \\
&=CT\prod_{i=1}^{2m-1}y_i^{i-2}(1+y_i)^{2m}\cdot\left(\det\left[(y_i^{-2})^{j-1}\right]\right) \\
&=CT\prod_{i=1}^{2m-1}y_i^{i-2}(1+y_i)^{2m}\cdot V(y_1^{-2},\dots,y_{2m-1}^{-2}).
\end{align}
The assertion follows from Corollary 1. $\square$

Comment: Often such identities are provable by induction using Desnanot–Jacobi (also known as Lewis Carroll's) identity https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dodgson_condensation

Comment: Have you looked at the eigenvalues of $A_m(x)$? There may be a a generalization of Holte's result.

Comment: It seems (3.13) in "advanced determinant calculus" contains this as a special case.

Comment: *Conjecture*. All the diagonal entries of the Smith normal of $A_m(x)$ over the ring $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ are squarefree (as polynomials in $x$). This uniquely determines the SNF. I checked this for $m\leq 10$ and could easily check some further cases. On the other hand, the eigenvalues do not look nice. The characteristic polynomial of $A_m(x)$ is irreducible for $1\leq m\leq 4$.

Comment: @RichardStanley: I've changed notation, so your conjecture is for $A_{2m-1}(x,0)$. Would it still hold for $A_n(x,\lambda)$?

Comment: @T.Amdeberhan: my conjecture seems also to be true for any positive integer $m$ and any integer $\lambda$.

Comment: I agree with @Suvrit that this is a special case of (3.13) in Krattenthaler's [Advanced determinant calculus](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/9902004) by setting $B=0, A=x, L_j = x-2j-\lambda$, and interchanging $i$ and $j$. Quote from the author's introduction *In fact, I claim that about 80 % of the
determinants that you meet in “real life,” and which can apparently be evaluated, are a special case of just the very first of these [lemmas]*.

Comment: The above proof appears simpler ...

Comment: @RichardStanley: You may like to see my question, part 3, on SNF at http://mathoverflow.net/questions/258448/in-search-of-a-transformation-between-determinants

Answer (score 14):

The matrix $A_n(x,\lambda)$ is obtained from the dual Jacobi matrix for the partition $\mu=(n+\lambda,n-1+\lambda,...,1+\lambda)$ by setting $x$ variables equal to 1 and the remaining variables equal to 0, and then permuting some rows and columns in such a way that keeps the sign of the determinant the same. Thus the determinant is just
$s_\mu(1^x)$, whose factorization is well-known. Moreover, my conjecture (appearing in a comment) about the Smith normal form of $A_n(x,\lambda)$ follows from my paper http://math.mit.edu/~rstan/papers/jtsnf.pdf.