# Eigenvalues and eigenvectors of the matrix with entries $\dbinom{n+1}{2j-i}$ for $i, j = 1, 2, \ldots, n$

Tags: co.combinatorics, eigenvalues, determinants, binomial-coefficients, algebraic-combinatorics

Let $n$ be a nonnegative integer, and let $B$ be the $n \times n$-matrix (over the rational numbers) whose $\left(i, j\right)$-th entry is $\dbinom{n+1}{2j-i}$ for all $i, j \in \left\{ 1, 2, \ldots, n \right\}$.

For example, if $n = 5$, then
\begin{equation}
B = \left(\begin{array}{rrrrr}
6 & 20 & 6 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 15 & 15 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 6 & 20 & 6 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 15 & 15 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 6 & 20 & 6
\end{array}\right) .
\end{equation}

> **Question 1.** Prove that the eigenvalues of $B$ are $2^1, 2^2, \ldots, 2^n$. (I know how to do this -- I'll write up the answer soon -- but there might be other approaches too.)
>
> **Question 2.** Find a left eigenvector for each of these eigenvalues. What I know is that the row vector $v$ whose $i$-th entry is $\left(-1\right)^{i-1} \dbinom{n-1}{i-1}$ (for $i \in \left\{1,2,\ldots,n\right\}$) is a left eigenvector for eigenvalue $2^1$ (that is, $v B = 2 v$). But the other left eigenvectors are a mystery to me.
>
> **Question 3.** Find a right eigenvector for each of these eigenvalues. For example, it appears to me that the column vector $w$ whose $i$-th entry is $\left(-1\right)^{i-1} / \dbinom{n-1}{i-1}$ (for $i \in \left\{1,2,\ldots,n\right\}$) is a right eigenvector for eigenvalue $2^1$ (that is, $B w = 2 w$). This (if correct) boils down to the identity
>   \begin{equation}
> \sum_{k=1}^n \left(-1\right)^{k-1} \left(k-1\right)! \left(n-k\right)! \dbinom{n+1}{2k-i} = 2 \left(-1\right)^{i-1} \left(i-1\right)! \left(n-i\right)!
> \end{equation}
>   for all $i \in \left\{1,2,\ldots,n\right\}$.
>   Note that the entries of $w$ are the reciprocals to the corresponding entries of $v$ ! Needless to say, this pattern doesn't persist, but maybe there are subtler patterns.

I am going to put up an answer to Question 1 soon, as a stepping stone for the proof of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2886392 , but this shouldn't keep you from adding your ideas or answers.

Comment: There is some connection with https://mathoverflow.net/questions/258284/is-the-matrix-left2m-choose-2j-i-right-i-j-12m-1-nonsingular

Comment: @JohannCigler: Thank you! This is noticeably simpler than my proof.

Comment: The right eigenvectors seem to be of this form. Fit a degree $n-1$ polynomial $p$ that takes the value $(-1)^{i-1}/{n-1\choose i-1}$ at $i$. Then the $i$th coordinate of the eigenvector corresponding to $2^{k+1}$ is $p^{(k)}(i)$.

Comment: Also, please, see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2884380/binary-eigenvalues-matrices-and-continued-fractions

Comment: It seems also that the Vandermonde matrix $V(1,2,\dots,n)$ upper-triangularizes $B$, but I do not see the pattern in the resulting matrix's entries.

Comment: @MTyson Can you be more precise? E.g. $V=\begin{pmatrix}1&1&1&1&1\\1&2&4&8&16\\ .&.&. \end{pmatrix}$, and then you mean $V^{-1}BV$ should be upper-triangular, or how? (I can't reproduce it)

Comment: @Wolfgang Yes, I believe those conventions should work.

Comment: @MTyson My bad, I had taken the wrong matrix for $B$. Now I have found experimentally that the diagonals of $V^{-1}BV$ are proportional to those of a matrix $A$ with $a_{i,j}=2^{n+1-j}\binom{j-1}{i-1}$, i.e. (more elegant with shifting indices) $A=(2^{n-j}\binom ji)_{i,j=0}^{n-1}$. But the ratios have big prime factors. :(

Comment: @Wolfgang: We can define two $n \times n$-matrices $W$ and $U$ by $W = \left(  \dbinom{i-1}{j-1}\right)  _{1\leq i\leq n,\ 1\leq j\leq n}$ and $U = \left(  2^{n+1-2j+i}\dbinom{n+1-j}{j-i}\right)  _{1\leq i\leq n,\ 1\leq j \leq n}$, and then we have $U = W^{-1} B W$. At least I'm quite sure about that, though I still haven't found the time to prove it. Note that the matrix $W$ and the claim that $W^{-1} B W$ is upper-triangular are due to Suvrit in the thread linked by Johann Cigler, but he didn't find the above-diagonal entries of $W^{-1} B W$ explicitly.

Comment: Then the claim by @MTyson that $V^{-1}BV$ is upper-triangular should follow from the fact that $V = UW$ for some invertible upper-triangular matrix $U$. And when I say "fact", I mean "this looks like it's true, but again I don't have the time right now".

Comment: How explicit a formula do you need for the eigenvectors? As $B$ is diagonalizable, there is always [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_covariant)...

Answer (score 11):

Here is a proof for your identity in Question 3: define the functions
\begin{equation}
F(n,k):=\frac{\left(-1\right)^{k-i} \left(k-1\right)! \left(n-k\right)!}
{2\left(i-1\right)! \left(n-i\right)!} \dbinom{n+1}{2k-i} 
\end{equation}
and 
\begin{equation}
G(n,k):=-\frac{F(n,k)\,(n-k+1)(2k-i-1)(2k-i)}{(n+1)(n+2-2k+i)(n-i+1)}
\end{equation}.
Then it is routine (e.g. using symbolic softwares) to check that
$$F(n+1,k)-F(n,k)=G(n,k+1)-G(n,k).$$
If you sum both sides over all integers $k$ (bearing in mind the binomials have finite support), the RHS vanishes. Thus $\sum_kF(n,k)$ is a constant. A simple check for say $n=1$ shows $\sum_kF(n,k)=1$ and this is what you desire to achieve.

The above method is known as the [Wilf-Zeilberger method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilf%E2%80%93Zeilberger_pair) of proof.

> This is an update to confirm darij grinberg's claim in the comments: $WU=BW$.

Define the two new functions ($i, j$ are suppressed)
$$F(n,k)=\binom{i-1}{k-1}2^{n+1-2j+k}\binom{n+1-j}{j-k}$$
and 
$$FF(n,k)=\binom{n+1}{2k-i}\binom{k-1}{j-1}.$$
Then there exist two companion functions $G(n,k)$ and $GG(n,k)$ such that
$$(i-2j+n+3)F(n+2,k)+(-2i+4j-3n-7)F(n+1,k)+(2n+4-2j)F(n,k)=G(n,k+1)-G(n,k)$$
and
$$(i-2j+n+3)FF(n+2,k)+(-2i+4j-3n-7)FF(n+1,k)+(2n+4-2j)FF(n,k)=GG(n,k+1)-GG(n,k).$$
As usual, sum over all integers $k$ to obtain that both $f(n)=\sum_kF(n,k)$ and $ff(n)=\sum_kFF(n,k)$ satisfy the same recurrence
$$(i-2j+n+3)f(n+2)+(-2i+4j-3n-7)f(n+1)+(2n+4-2j)f(n)=0,$$
$$(i-2j+n+3)ff(n+2)+(-2i+4j-3n-7)ff(n+1)+(2n+4-2j)ff(n)=0.$$
After checking at two initial values, say $n=1$ and $n=2$, it follows that $f(n)=ff(n)$. That completes the proof.

Comment: (1) Could it be that $F(n+1,k)-F(n,k)=G(n,k+1)-G(n,k)$ should be $F(n+1,k)-F(n,k)=G(n,k)-G(n,k+1)$ instead? (2) Am I right in assuming that you set $F\left(n,k\right) = 0$ if $n < k$ or $n < i$ ?

Comment: You are right on both counts: (1) I've modified $G(n,k)$ with a minus sign; (2) my comment "compact support" was addressing the convention you pointed out.

Answer (score 4):

The left eigenvectors seem to be related to the [Euler polynomials](http://oeis.org/wiki/Eulerian_polynomials) (note that these are referred to in Wikipedia as [Eulerian polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eulerian_number)).

For fixed  $1\le k\le n$, if the left eigenvector for the eigenvalue $2^k$ is denoted $(v_1,\dots,v_n)$ and normalized to $v_1=1$, then it appears that $$ \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n v_ix^i}{(1-x)^{n+1}}=x+2^kx^2+3^kx^3+\cdots$$ which allows to find the $v_i$ recursively, keeping $k$ and increasing $n$.
For $k=n$ (i.e. for the biggest eigenvalue), $\sum_{i=1}^n v_ix^{i-1}$ is the $n$th Euler polynomial.